# Create and delete my MWAA everyday in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, mwaa

I have created my MWAA cloud formation template, but I have not yet created the solution that deletes and creates every day at a certain time this environment from my template. I tried to find out how to create this solution but I couldn't. Could someone give me a light how to connect what I already have or a documentation or even someone on Github who already went through this? Thanks a lot!

Create and delete my MWAA everyday in AWS

Comment: You could schedule an AWS Lambda function. Then, code the Lambda function to create/delete the CloudFormation stack.